# Function pointer in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to write a function that returns pointer in python.

```
class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Table", c_int), ("Chair", c_int),("Fan", c_int)]

Furniture=MyStruct() 

def foo():
    Furniture.Table=3
    return Table
```

I need to return address of the member `Table`.

Comment: Why do you think you need pointers? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: How to implement pointer in python

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the address? What's wrong with using references?

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers. So if that's literally what you're trying to do, the answer is simple: you can't do it. But it's very likely that what you _really_ want has nothing to do with pointers, and is easily doable...

Comment: I'm failing to see what's wrong about this question, when you integrate Python with C code, you happen to use pointers.

Comment: @bereal: that depends on how you're integrating, and what you're trying to do. With ctypes, yes, sometimes you need pointers. But the problem doesn't mention anything about ctypes; you can make a wild guess based on some of the type names, but as written the question is nonsense.

Comment: @abarnert `c_int` and `_fields_` make it quite safe to assume it's about ctypes.

Comment: @bereal: I already said "it looks like you're using `ctypes` here" in my answer, and explained how to do any of the three or four things he might be asking for (none of which are function pointers, of course).

Comment: @all: Actually i need to define a function in python which should return address of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using ctypes here.

In ctypes, you create a pointer type by using POINTER(type), then create an instance of that type the same way as any other ctypes type.

Or you can call addressof to get a pointer to some existing ctypes object.

Or you can call byref if you just need a pointer you can pass to a C function, without needing to see it as a pointer from within your python code.

All of this is explained pretty clearly in the ctypes docs. Without knowing what you're trying to actually do, I can't explain which one is relevant or how to use it, but if you read the docs and can't understand what to do, hopefully you'll at least be able to ask a specific, answerable question.